# Python <and><or> confusion

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

This is my first ever post. I am a very new learner of programming language at the age of 30. The language I am learning is python and I dont seem to understand what the basic flaw of my simple programming code is.

```
    a = input("What is the string?")
    b = input("Enter a number:")
    if(a == "Animal" and b == 1):
        print("No 1 Executed!")
    elif(a == "Dog"):
        print("No 2 Executed")
    else:
        print("No 3 Executed")
```

Even if I type "Animal" and Number 1, line no.3 is executed instead of line no. 1. Can you guys please explain what is my basic fault here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

b is a string and if you compare it with a number the result is false. You should use:

```
    if(a == "Animal" and b == "1"):
```

You could also convert b to number with int(b)

Comment: you don't need `()` for `if`s in python.

Comment: MSeifert, you're right, but fernand0 just modified his code. This comment should be under the original question and directed to Ahsan uzZaman

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the input function returns a String. That means that the variable b will be a string and in your if statement you are checking to see if it is equal to a number. You can fix this in several ways, one example would be to change your if statement to:

```
 if(a == "Animal" and b == "1"):
```

Answer (score 0):

the input command will always create a string, so even though you type in 1, python interprets that value as a string. `b == 1` is expecting b to be a number, so the expression is always false. There's 2 ways you could fix it.

If you want to keep b as a string, just change that expression to compare against a string, ie `b == "1"`

If you want b as a number, convert it to an integer immediately after `b = input("Enter a number:")`, just add a new line: `b = int(b)`. Now your expression will work as expected, but the program will fail if you enter any value that's not a number.

Comment: Thanks for your very elaborate answer..helped me a lot to understand it..I will be coming back to bug you guys more!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the latest line is executed is `input` returns `str` object which is not equal to number. To make it comparable as you want, you need to convert `b` to `int`.

```
b = int(input("Enter a number:"))
```